# Click and download excel file with Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Tried to download with Selenium and Python , the excel file by clicking the button on page but failed. Following is the class extracted from page:

```
<div class="tabPanel_func ts2_icon_map ts2_icon_excel" onclick="ExportExcel('tblTS2', tsData);"\>\</div\>`
```

I also want to download the file and then save to the specific drive location.

Following is my code :

```
url = "http://www.aastocks.com/tc/stocks/market/high-low-stocks.aspx?catg=1&period=3&t=1"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
```

Code trials:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//\[contains(@onclick, ExportExcel('tblTS2', tsData)')\]")`
```

or

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//\*\[@class= 'tabPanel_func ts2_icon_map ts2_icon_excel'\]")`
```

or

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "//button\[contains(@onclick,'ExportExcel('tblTS2', tsData)')\]").click()`
```

All approaches have failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CLASS_NAME*:

  ```
  driver.get('http://www.aastocks.com/tc/stocks/market/high-low-stocks.aspx?catg=1&period=3&t=1')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "ts2_icon_excel"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('http://www.aastocks.com/tc/stocks/market/high-low-stocks.aspx?catg=1&period=3&t=1')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ts2_icon_excel[onclick^='ExportExcel']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('http://www.aastocks.com/tc/stocks/market/high-low-stocks.aspx?catg=1&period=3&t=1')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@onclick, 'ExportExcel')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: ExportExcel]

Comment: It works, thanks ! What if I want to download the file to a specific drive and location instead of download to my C drive "Download" ? Do you have any suggestions on good books which cover these knowledge that I can read and learn other than stack overflow?

Comment: I tried '''options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory":r"D:/"})                                      
s = Service('chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)'''                                                    but failed to download.

Comment: Sounds like a separate question. Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement.

Comment: Thanks ! Will do and raise new question for this .

Answer (score 0):

Try the below XPath expression:

`//*[contains(@class,'tabPanel_func ts2_icon_map ts2_icon_excel')]`

**XPath explanation:** Searches the entire DOM(`//*`) which contains attribute = `class` and its value = `tabPanel_func ts2_icon_map ts2_icon_excel`

Above XPath expression will locate the below element:

[image]

Below is the full line of code to click the <kbd>Export</kbd> button:

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(@class,'tabPanel_func ts2_icon_map ts2_icon_excel')]").click()`

Answer (score 0):

Try following `xpath` to click on export excel.

```
//div[contains(@onclick,'ExportExcel')]
```

**code**:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@onclick,'ExportExcel')] 
"))).click()
```